# Issue updating rows on a sorted DataGridView with a DataTable DataSource

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datatable, sql-update

I have a Win Forms app in VB.NET 4.5.  In it, I use a `DataGridView` with a `DataTable` as its `DataSource` and a well-defined `SqlDataAdapter` to keep everything concurrent.  The `DataTable` is first filled by a Sql Server command and then bound like so:

```
Dim dt_Fishes AS New DataTable
Dim da_Fishes = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FishesKey, NetKey, b, c, d, e, (etc) FROM tblFishes WHERE NetKey = @NetKey;", conn)
da_Fishes.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetKey", intNetKey)
Dim cmdbld_Fishes As New SqlCommandBuilder(da_Fishes)
dt_Fishes.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Try
  conn.Open()
  da_Fishes.Fill(dt_Fishes)
Catch ex As Exception
  ' etc
Finally
  conn.close()
End Try
da_Fishes.DeleteCommand = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.tblFishes WHERE FishesKey = @FishesKey;", conn)
da_Fishes.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@FishesKey", SqlDbType.Int)
dgv_Fishes.DataSource = dt_Fishes
FormatDGV(dgv_Fishes) ' adds DataGridViewComboBoxColumns and colours, hides keys, etc
```

This is all working fine when the data are not sorted - inserts, updates, and deletes are functioning as they should while going through a row-level validation.  Row-level validation fires once the user leaves the row they're working on.

When the user clicks on a column header, the `DataGridView` visually sorts the data as you would expect (great!).  My issue is that when the user then proceeds to edit a row in the sorted `DataGridView`, and leaves that row (via the enter or down keyboard keys), no validation event is fired.  Curiously, if the user then keys to a cell of the row-number in the `DataGridView` that normally belongs to the edited data row, and then leaves that, then validation fires and the data update successfully occurs.

How do I force the `RowValidating` event to happen when the user leaves the edited row as normal when the `DataGridView` is sorted?

Comment: Which validation events exactly are you using and how do you know they arent firing?  Note that with a fully defined DataAdapter, you dont need to issue a new query to apply a filter: just use the DataTable.DefaultView.

Comment: @Plutonix normally when I leave a dirty row, the `RowValidating` event fires (where I test the entry for validation); if it gets all the way through `RowValidating` without being cancelled, then `RowValidated` fires (where my DataTable.AcceptChanges command sits).  I know it's not firing these events because if I "refresh" my `DataGridView` before scrolling over the original row, then any edits made to the row on the sorted table are lost.

Comment: I cant reproduce what you described, but I am not sure `AcceptChanges()` does what you think.  It should be used after `DataAdapter.Update()`.  Update applies all pending changes to the DB (you need not update row by row - the DT knows which are added, changed or deleted).  AcceptChanges then clears all those flags effectively synching the DT to the DB state.  If the DA is *fully* configured there is no need to "refresh" the DT, DGV or anything else: So, your Validated code is throwing them away it sounds like..not sure how sorting plays into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the red herring:

On further investigation, the `RowValidating` event is indeed firing when leaving a row.  Then the `RowValidated` event fires, but my problem seems to occur when I check the `DataTable`'s row-state.  After sorting the `DataGridView`, it and the underlying `DataTable` no longer have similar row numbers.  Which is why this `if`-statement is the culprit of my problems:

```
Private Sub dgv_RowValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv_Main.RowValidated
  Dim dgv_Sender As DataGridView = sender
  QueryAction = dt_Sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).RowState
  If dt_Sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).RowState <> DataRowState.Unchanged Then
    da_Fishes.Update(dt_Fishes)
```

And so, I need an alternate way to check the row states (the purpose of the `if`-statement is to minimize unnecessary updates).

Given this, my original question of

> Issue updating rows on a sorted DataGridView with a DataTable
>   DataSource

has been resolved, as I'll now switch gears to sorting out a different way to perform the above check on a sorted `DataGridView`...